# Facing an issue with executing python package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-packaging

I am learning python packages but I am stuck with this issue: I created one package folder "SamplePack". Inside this folder, I have added 2 module files with .py extension and an __ init __.py file as a constructor as below:

**Mod2.py**

```
from math import *

def sqroot(x):
    return sqrt(x)

def sine(x):
    return sin(x)

def cos(x):
    return cos(x)

def power(x,y):
    return pow(x,y)
```

**Mod1.py**

```
def Add(x,y):
    return x+y

def Div(x,y):
    return x-y

def function():
    x=input("What's your name? ")
    y=input("Great", x, "What's your phone number? ")
```

**__ init __.py**

```
import Mod1
import Mod2
```

Post this, I created the package source file from which I will execute these package modules.

**Packuse.py**

```
import SamplePack as sp

sp.Mod1.Add(20,20)
sp.Mod2.sqrt(30)
sp.Mod1.function()
```

When I executed the Packuse.py file through python prompt. I got this error:

> C:\Users\Program>python packuse.py Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File "C:\Users\Program\packuse.py", line 1,
> in 
> import SamplePack as sp   File "C:\Users\Program\SamplePack_*init*_.py", line 1, in
>
> import Mod1 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Mod1'

Comment: Isn't the name `module` reserved by Python ? Try renaming it into something else. Also, naming your file `math` and trying to import it while a math module already exists isn't a good idea.

Comment: Ah! right. I renamed the module files to Mod1 and Mod2. Now again getting a different set of error here and updated my given problem statement above. Do you have any idea why is it so? @Kyrela

Comment: If Mod1 is *inside* SamplePack, then its name is `SamplePack.Mod1`, not `Mod1`, and you need to use that name inside `import` statements, regardless of where they are. Or you explicitly use a *relative* `import .Mod1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's your file architecture :

```
Program
├- packuse.py
└- SamplePack
   ├- __init__.py
   ├- Mod1.py
   └- Mod2.py
```

You're launching your code from the `Program` directory, So the working directory is `Program`.

When you import SamplePack from `packuse.py`, it looks through the working directory for a directory named `SamplePack` of a file named `SamplePack.py`.

But when you import `Mod1` from `__init__.py`, it also looks through the working directory, wich is always `Program`, and not `SamplePack`. So it doessn't find it, because there aren't any `Mod1` directory or `Mod1.py` file in `Program`.

What you need to do is to precise that the import system should look for the specified package or module, starting from the package directory (in this case, `SamplePack`).

Here's how to do it :

###### __init__.py :

```py
from . import Mod1
from . import Mod2
```

The `.` indicates that it should looks from the actual file's parent directory, and not from the working directory. Note that this only works in package files.

Comment: Actually I tried using .Mod1 and .Mod2 also but it is throwing this error.  I use Python 3.6 version. 


C:\Users\Program>python packuse.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Program\packuse.py", line 1, in <module>
    import SamplePack as sp
  File "C:\Users\Program\SamplePack\__init__.py", line 1
    import .Mod1
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I edited it with a similar method, can you give it a try ?